# How to keep the best 500 Keypoints from an Arraylist in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, opencv, arraylist

I am writing code for Android to limit the number of Keypoints I have from the FAST detector (now i get about 9000 keypoints). I want to keep the best 500 Keypoints, based on the Response. I made a comparator that can sort these keypoints according to their response. Now I want to find a way to get the 500 best keypoints, and put these in a new List.

Here is the code I have

```
// gets the keypoints from the detector, and puts them in a list
List<KeyPoint> pointstest = points1.toList();
                // comparator orders the keypoints (check image for output)
                order(pointstest);
                    // make a new list to put the 500 best keypoints in
                List<KeyPoint> nieuw = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>();
```

So I now need to "recreate" the List with the best points, but I'm currently stuck on how to fix this. Does anyone have a suggestion? I was thinking about a for loop maybe, but can it be implemented for these keypoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
List<KeyPoint> nieuw = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>(pointstext.subList(0, 500));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should combine @Ashwini Bhangi and @Peter Lawrey suggestions: first [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) your List, then get a sublist from 0 to 499.

Comparators are formally `Comparator<T>`, in your case `Comparator<KeyPoint>`, so:

```
int count = 500;
Collections.sort(keypoints, new Comparator<KeyPoint>() {
    public int compare(KeyPoint o1, KeyPoint o2) {
        //TODO add code for deciding values to compare on
        // Note that here you should implement DESCENDING logic 
        // to get greater values at the beginning, not at the end
        return value;
   }
});
```

Then get the sublist:

```
List<KeyPoint> theBest = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>(keypoints.subList(0, count));
```

Keep in mind that sorting the original list modifies it in place. If you want to preserve the original list, you should make a copy prior to sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Use Collections sort so that you can choose which values you want in the list of 500.

```
    List<Object> sortedArray = new ArrayList<Object>(count);
    Collections.sort(sortedArray, new Comparator<Object>() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                    //TODO add code for deciding values to compare on
            return value;
           }
    });
```

Comment: that wasn't really my problem, I already had that part implemented in my code, hence the order(pointstest); but thanks you anyway for the answer!